# Java Charting libraries

Tags: java, charts

I'm looking for a good charting library for Java. It can be open source or not and I need it to work in a stand alone client application rather than web-based.

We do have some dynamic charts however which scroll across the screen as data are provided that were done in MS chart and will need to be redone so not sure if JChart will accomplish this in an acceptable manner.

Are there any java charting libraries right in the J2SE API? I've also run across Oracle Chart Builder, but can't seem to find any information on it other than this link: http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A96127_01/jcb_intro.htm Has anyone ever heard of it before?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java graph or chart library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527640/java-graph-or-chart-library)

Comment: [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is an excellent open source charting library for java.

The samples demo ([Java Web Start version](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) or in the [distribution](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/)) contains a section under Miscellaneous called Dynamic Charts (in addition to lots of others).  The source code for the demos is available via the official documentation (the purchase of which supports the project).

Comment: I've used JFreeChart in the past, and I highly recommend purchasing the official documentation. It is well written and extremely useful. Plus it is inexpensive, and helps support the project.

Comment: What do I need to open that demo? I'd seen it on the site as well, but after saving, couldn't open it with a browser. Thank you.

Comment: @agezna - You should just be able to double click on it to launch it.  If that doesn't work, download the latest distribution (see link above) which, in addition to the charting libraries, has the samples all wrapped up in a single jar.  Run the command ``java -jar jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jar`` from a command prompt to launch the demo.

Comment: Ah, new PC didn't have the JVM installed works fine now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ - I used it for small project. Rendering dynamic data was quite complex but possible.

It's open source but you probably will have to pay for doc if you would like to do something serious.